# How to multi-thread parsing of JMS messages

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, synchronized

In my Spring Boot project, I have two JMS listeners listening to one queue. All messages received from the queue have to be processed in the same way and persisted / updated in the database (Oracle). Currently, I have a synchronized method in a class that is doing the parsing of the messages. As expected, all thread read messages simultaneously, but parsing is done one by one as the method (`parseMessage()`) is synchronized. What I want is to parse the messages simultaneously and do database operations as well.

How can I solve this?

I don't want to create two different classes with the same code and use `@Qualifier` to call different classes in each listener, as the code for parsing the message is the same.

The ideal solution, I think, is to do database operations using a new synchronized method in a new class, but parsing the message in a multi-threaded way. So, at a time only one thread can say persist / update. When a thread is not waiting to persist / update, it continues the parsing on its own thread.

Please correct me if I am wrong or if you find the optimal solution. Let me know if any other info is needed.

#### JMS Controller Class

```java
@RestController
@EnableJms
public class JMSController {

    @Autowired
    private IParseMapXml iParseMapXml;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${app.jms_destinaltion}")
    public void receiveMessage1(String recvMsg) {
        try {
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(recvMsg.replaceAll("&", "&amp")));
            Document doc = new SAXReader().read(is);
            iParseMapXml.parseMessage(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${app.jms_destinaltion}")
    public void receiveMessage2(String recvMsg) {
        try {
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(recvMsg.replaceAll("&", "&amp")));
            Document doc = new SAXReader().read(is);
            iParseMapXml.parseMessage(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

#### Parse XML Interface

```java
public interface IParseMapXml {
    
    public void parseMessage(Document doc);

}
```

#### Parsing Implementation

```java
public class ParsingMessageClass implements IParseMapXml{

    @Override
    @Transactional
    synchronized public void parseMessage(Document doc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ....
        PROCESS DATA/MESSAGE

        ....
        DO DB OPERATIONS
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is your code synchronized? If properly written, you wouldn't need to synchronize parsing, nor the database operations.

Comment: because if i don't have it synchronized, and when two threads enter the same method (`parseMessage()`). Both are accessing the same method objects/variable at the same time with diff message data (i.e. hashcode of any method variable is same for both the thread when both listeners run simultaneously).

Comment: To me, that is a sign to implement the parser differently, not that it should be synchronized.